# MailApp.sendEmail method signature exception: The parameters (class) don't match

Tags: google-apps-script, email-attachments

I'm trying to attach a file with an email i'm sending through Google Sheet Script:
"Exception: The parameters (number[],String,String,**(class)**) don't match the method signature for MailApp.sendEmail."

I've tried the function "MailApp.sendEmail" with the methods (number[],String,String) and it worked properly, however when adding the attachment part, it's failing...

```
    var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("why abilix.PDF");
    var emailBody = textTemplate[0][0].replace("{patient.name}",patientNames[i][0])
                                .replace("{stage}",phase[j]);
    var emailAddress = patientEmails[i];
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailBody, **{
                      name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
                      attachments: [file1.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]}**);
```

Comment: try removing those asterisks

Comment: The asterisks were added by the text editor while trying to make this section in Bold.
The problem is that the whole part between the asterisks is considered as a "class", which is an undefined type of parameter to be set in "MailApp.sendEmail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailAddress, subject: mySubject, htmlBody: emailBody, 
     attachments: [file1.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     })
```

may be subject can also cause an error ... change the term!

Comment: "subject" value was defined previously in the code, the problem is with the "class" not being recognized as a parameter in "MailApp.sendEmail".

Comment: If you need more help, please share a sample sheet. What I have posted works fine for me.. Be carefull to th location of  Curly Brackets

Comment: I've copied the piece of code that you wrote, and used it as it is, i got "Exception: Invalid email".
So i amended it as follows:
"to: emailAddress.toString()"
And it worked...
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thx for the feed-back, in iact it depends on the type of emailAddress.